# npm install fails because node-gyp is failing. HOW to Fix?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

I recently attempted to do a clean install for our project.  But now npm install is failing on Ubuntu 17.04. I have changed the version of node, npm, node-gyp and python I am using with no success.

Is this due to a change to node-gyp or something else?
Running:

```
 node-gyp rebuild
```

Gives me:

```
    gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
    gyp info using node@7.10.1 | linux | x64
    gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
    gyp info spawn args [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
    gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
    gyp info spawn args   '-f',
    gyp info spawn args   'make',
    gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    gyp info spawn args   '/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/build/config.gypi',
    gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
    gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    gyp info spawn args   '/home/joel/.node-gyp/7.10.1/include/node/common.gypi',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/joel/.node-gyp/7.10.1',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/joel/.node-gyp/7.10.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
    gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
    gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
    gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
    gyp info spawn args   'build',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
    gyp info spawn make
    gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
    make: Entering directory '/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/build'
    make: *** No rule to make target 'Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o', needed by 'Release/obj.target/binding.node'.  Stop.
    make: Leaving directory '/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/build'
    gyp ERR! build error 
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
    gyp ERR! System Linux 4.11.3-041103-generic
    gyp ERR! command "/home/joel/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3
    gyp ERR! node -v v7.10.1
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
    gyp ERR! not ok
```

Does anyone have any ideas what causes this?  And how to debug and fix?

Answer (score 0):

Run this command `sudo apt-get install build-essential` on ubuntu and try it again.

Also please see [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/) as it's recommended in here.

You can see [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/809)  for more info on how to restart.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I already had build-essential installed, but restarted anyway.  removed ~/.node-gyp, node_modules, ~/.npmrc and tried again. Still NO GO!  I also installed apt-get install libkrb5-dev just as a possible solution.  But nothing worked.

Comment: I have this project on another machine that has the same issue.  So perhaps this has something to do with a recent update to Ubuntu 17.04 --- I will let my brain stop being fried and try again in another hour.  I hate ti when this S happens out of the blue.

Comment: I am running on a RYZEN machine, so I even updated to the latest kernel 4.12.0 to see if that helped, but no change.

Comment: there must be a solution, don't get your brain fried! )) @JoelParke

Comment: @JoelParke have you tried to install it like this? `sudo npm i -g node-gyp --unsafe-perm`

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help.

Comment: The latest: I updated all the packages to current. Updated typescript to the .next and switched to yarn which is at least faster.  Also I needed to switch to the latest rxjs (alpha) due to the latest typescript which is much pickier.  Also removed node_modules with rimraf.   Still stuck, but the project is at least up to date and eventually I will find what the issue is I am sure.

Comment: I added an answer - that is not an answer.  Since when I go desperate and eliminated everything from the package.json file, I still can't run 'npm install' and it seems the issue is with node-gyp and perhaps something I need in the package.json to keep it from attempting to do a node-gyp.  which I have never run into before.

Answer (score 0):

This is now an answer! as it turns out that there was a left over 'binding.gyp' in the root of the project that was causing ALL the issues since it could not build anything!!! Naturally my first assumption that this was due to the packages was completely wrong....

Simplifying and removing everything down to:

```
{
  "name": "Tracker3",
  "version": "3.1.0",
  "description": "A todo list and shared tracker",
  "keywords": [
    "angular",
    "angular4",
    "webpack",
    "typescript"
  ],
  "author": "Joel Parke <joel@Dynazu.com>",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
  },
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/issues"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.2.1",
    "npm": ">= 3"
  }
}
```

where there is nothing in the package at all now gives:

```
yarn
yarn install v0.27.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
$ node-gyp rebuild
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.5.0
gyp info using node@7.10.1 | linux | x64
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
gyp info spawn args [ '/home/joel/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/joel/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/joel/.node-gyp/7.10.1/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/joel/.node-gyp/7.10.1',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/home/joel/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
make: Entering directory '/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/build'
make: *** No rule to make target 'Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o', needed by 'Release/obj.target/binding.node'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory '/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/joel/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.12.0-041200-generic
gyp ERR! command "/home/joel/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.1/bin/node" "/home/joel/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3
gyp ERR! node -v v7.10.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.5.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

**SO it turned out that this 'binding.gyp' file that was left around at some point was causing all the problems.**
  Removing this file and restoring everything back gives:

```
yarn:

yarn install v0.27.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.12s.
joel@parke:~/workspace/Tracker3$ yarn
yarn install v0.27.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
warning fsevents@1.1.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "ngrx-store-freeze@0.1.9" has incorrect peer dependency "@ngrx/store@^2.2.1".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
$ npm run webdriver:update

> Tracker3@3.1.0 webdriver:update /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3
> webdriver-manager update

webdriver-manager: using local installed version 12.0.6
[12:02:08] I/file_manager - creating folder /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium
[12:02:09] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.31.zip
[12:02:09] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.31
[12:02:11] I/update - geckodriver: unzipping geckodriver-v0.18.0.tar.gz
[12:02:11] I/update - geckodriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.18.0
Done in 36.46s.
```

which is correct as expected.  HOPEFULLY this will help someone else at some point!  Thanks for all that looked at this! Especially, https://stackoverflow.com/users/8377060/jack-delson

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get the "No rule to make target..." error is for the file(s) specified in `binding.gyp` to be wrong. If the filenames in the `sources` key aren't found you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, resolved by doing the following:

1. Removed old Command Line Tools

   **sudo rm -rf $(xcode-select -print-path)**

   And reinstalled:

   **xcode-select --install**
2. Downgraded the node version from 11 to 8.16.1

   **sudo npm install -g n**

   **sudo n stable**

   **sudo n 8.16.1**

   In the end, check your node version:

   **node -v**